# Email App On Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: email

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.There is an app called thunderbird for email. I don't want use this email app. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What decent email client would you recommend (at least better than Thunderbird)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/219055/what-decent-email-client-would-you-recommend-at-least-better-than-thunderbird)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [Geary](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Geary). It has a very clean interface and is quite lightweight.

[image]

To install, enter the following in a Terminal -

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yorba/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install geary`

Comment: can i use gmail,yahoo and hotmail on it?

Comment: Yes. In fact any IMAP based mail. The link mentioned above in the answer confirms the same.